# Getting error while trying to install skype in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, skype

I am trying to install `skype` in Ubuntu 12.04 and getting this error while doing so

```
E: The package skype:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I had followed steps provided in [these links](http://www.umunthu.net/howtos/how-install-skype-ubuntu-1204-lts) and [this](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-skype-in-ubuntu.html) but same thing happens. Though I didn't tried with Ubuntu software center.

I am not able to identify what is causing trouble.

How can i fix this?

Comment: what is the result of `apt-cache madison skype` ?

Comment: @DuminduMahawela: here is the result of `apt-cache madison skype` ,  `skype | 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 | http://archive.canonical.com/ precise/partner amd64 Packages
     skype | 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 | http://archive.canonical.com/ precise/partner Sources`

Comment: So its going to install it from the main repository. When did you receive this message ? while trying to install with downloaded from skype or when use `apt-get install skype'?

Comment: @DuminduMahawela: yes, i get this message while i tried to download skype through `apt-het install skype` and now even after trying every possible thing, i am unable to fix this.While searching even i get a suggestion,that may be i have to re-install ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It seems that Main ubuntu repository has removed skype. [See](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=skype&searchon=names). Previously thare was the exact package name `skype`. Now not there. (in the list are other stuff). So the solution given in below answer seems better. Before doing it purge the present content. `sudo apt-get purge skype`.

Comment: @DuminduMahawela: even i am using `sudo apt-get purge skype` or `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skype` i am unable to remove skype

Comment: Run `gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`. In the resulting text file search for the **sections** start with `Package : skype`. Delete the whole **section**. If not yet resolved, see weather there is a `.deb` file of skype in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` folder. ( even in `partial` subfolder).

Comment: @DuminduMahawela: Your reply work for me.After removing all the sections starting with `Package : skype`, it works !

Answer (score 1):

Delete skype (recommended Completely removal), Download it from http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ , and reinstall.

Comment: I am not even able to remove skype completely.I am using `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skype` and now it's not even allowing me to install any thing on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Try `Synaptic package meneger`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install synaptic` for install

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the package `skype` has been configured as installed.

Perhaps it may be due to your previous installation attempts.

Data about configured packages are stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/` folder. in further, details about Installed packages stored in it's `status` sub folder. So it seems manual removing of that wrong detail is needed.

Run :

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the resulting text file search for the **sections** start with

```
Package : skype
```

Delete the **whole section**.

Then run updating and try to install it again.